# How to parse XML with several Attributes and an options list

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, xmlserializer, xml-attribute

I have an XML file that looks something similar to this:

```
<root>
    <data label="product data" min="0" max="10">
        <option>
            <id>1</id>
            <name>Name1</name>
        </option>
        <option>
            <id>2</id>
            <name>Name2</name>
        </option>
        <option>
            <id>3</id>
            <name>Name3</name>
        </option>
    </data>
</root>
```

I need to retreive both `data` attributes and the option list.

I tried this:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "root")]
public class Data
{
    // Retreive data attributes
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "data")]
    public Options Attributes { get; set; }

    // Retrieve option list
    [XmlArray("data")]
    [XmlArrayItem("option", Type = typeof(GeneralOptions))]
    public GeneralOptions[] Options { get; set; }
}
```

Optional classes:

**Options**

```
public class Options
{
    [XmlAttribute("label")]
    public string Label{ get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("min")]
    public string Min{ get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("max")]
    public string Max{ get; set; }
}
```

**GeneralOptions**

```
public class GeneralOptions
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "name")]
    public string Name{ get; set; }
}
```

But when I try to deserialize the object, it launches the following exception:

> The XML element 'data' from namespace '' is already present in the current scope. Use XML attributes to specify another XML name or namespace for the element.

I imagine the problem is that I'm trying to retreive the same element "twice". But I need to retreive both things. I cannot use the `[Attribute]` thing because there are several Attributes to retreive, and I need to do this with several XML Elements with the same format and I want to reuse it.

So, how can I retreive both of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to restructure it slightly:

```cs
[XmlRoot("root")]
public class Data
{
    [XmlElement("data")]
    public OptionsData Options { get; set; }
}

public class OptionsData
{
    [XmlAttribute("label")]
    public string Label { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("min")]
    public string Min { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("max")]
    public string Max { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("option")]
    public List<GeneralOptions> Items { get; } = new List<GeneralOptions>();
}

public class GeneralOptions
{
    [XmlElement("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: (For others who were initially confused, the `Data` class models the `<root>` element, and the `OptionsData` class models the `<data>` element)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [xmltocsharp](https://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/) or anyother tools to convert the XML to C# Models within seconds... (eliminates all manual mistakes)

> As mentioned by @canton7, another easy method is using `Visual Studio: Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste XML As Classes`

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName="option")]
public class Option {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="data")]
public class Data {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="option")]
    public List<Option> Option { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="label")]
    public string Label { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="min")]
    public string Min { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="max")]
    public string Max { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="root")]
public class Root {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="data")]
    public Data Data { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: (Note that there's one built into Visual Studio: Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste XML As Classes. It generates very verbose C#, though)